# After running regression, how do I get rid of columns that get negative coefficients and re-run the regression with remaining columns? Using Python

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, linear-regression

My code is performing regression on a few hundred scenarios with a loop. My goal is to get rid of columns that return negative coefficients and perform regression again with the remaining columns. This is the code within the loop:

```
X = regressionDF.iloc[:,0:11]
y = regressionDF.iloc[:,11].squeeze()
lm = linear_model.LinearRegression
lm.fit(X,y)
cf= lm.coef_
```

This returns an array of 11 coefficients. Once I get rid of columns with negative coefficients and running regression again, I want to still be able to print out the coefficients as an 11-element array with the coefficients of the columns ignored as zero. Something like this:

```
[0.0375, 0, 0.475, 0.064, 0.536, 0, 0, 0.324, 0.273, 0, 0]
```

Any idea how I may be able to do that? Thank you!

Comment: Is this [tag:pandas]?

Comment: For my model, I'm using a combination of pandas, statsmodels, and sklearn.